# VBA Excel Get Color Conditional Formatting Ico

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I am trying to get the colour of a set of conditional formatting's rule.

Here an example:
[image]

I am trying to get the colour of the arrow with the following method:

```
Sheet2.Cells(rwIndex, colIndex).Interior.ColorIndex
```

But is not working as I expected.

I tried to use also this function `Sheet2.Cells(rwIndex, colIndex).Font.Color`
And surprise, as I expected I get the desired colour.

[image]

Is there a way to get the colour of the arrow of the conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

I found two helpful pages:

To get the background color of the cell if a Conditional Format is applied, you'd need:
Range.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color  , see e.g. this page: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/CFColors.htm

For the icons: you'd need to loop through the Range.FormatConditions and check which one applies. But still, I haven't been able to find the color of the icons, this is the list of all available icons: https://bettersolutions.com/excel/macros/enumerations-xlicon.htm and this are the IconSets: https://bettersolutions.com/excel/macros/enumerations-xliconset.htm , however, there seems to be no way to check out which individual icons are in an IconSet (which would be practical if you would make a custom set).

Hope that gets you started!

Comment: Hello, thanks very much for the reply. I was looking at the properties you shared in your post, and it is a good start point, but unfortunately it does not drive me anywhere else. It is indeed a good start point, but I am starting to think that there is no way to get the colour.